# How do I render form fields in my custom.tpl.php template?

Tags: 7, entities

Here's my dilemma, I built a custom form-based module that allows a user to vote on a future conference location but I'm having a issue printing or rendering my form fields to have them display in my custom block template.

### **eventvoting.module**

```
<?php
/**
 * @file
 * Title        : Drupal 7 Event Voting form in a block pattern with template file
 * Author       : Kenyon M. Johnston
 *
 * Web application form that allows site visitors to vote on what city they
 * would like to see host their favorite event next year. 
 */


 /**
 * Implmentation of hook_permission()
 */
function eventvoting_permission(){
  return array (
    'Administer event voting form' => array(
      'title' => t('Administer event voting form'),
      'description' => t('Allows users to implement custom css class for the Event Voting Form module'),
    )
  );
}

 /**
 * Implements hook_block_info().
 */
function eventvoting_block_info() {
  $block['eventvoting_block'] = array(
    'info' => t('Event Voting Form Block'),
    'cache' => DRUPAL_CACHE_PER_ROLE,
  );  
  return $block;
}

/**
 * Implementation of hook_block_view()
 */
function eventvoting_block_view($delta = '') {
  $block = array();

  switch ($delta) {
    case 'eventvoting':
      $block['subject'] = t('');
      $block['content'] = array(
        '#theme' => 'eventvoting',
        '#vote_event_name' => variable_get('event_name'),
        '#vote_city' => variable_get('city'),
        '#vote_name' => variable_get('name'),
        '#vote_email' => variable_get('email'),
        '#vote_submit' => variable_get('submit'),
      );
    break;
  }
  return $block;
}

/*
 * Implements hook_theme
 */
function eventvoting_theme(){
  return array (
    'eventvoting' => array (
      'arguments' => array(
        'vote_event_name' => NULL,
        'vote_city' => NULL,
        'vote_name' => NULL,
        'vote_email' => NULL,
        'vote_submit' => NULL,
      ),
      // Use a template file called eventtheme.tpl.php
      'template' => 'theme/eventtheme',
    ),
  );
}

/**
 * Implements hook_menu().
*/
function eventvoting_menu() {
  $items['event-voting-form'] = array(
    'title' => 'Event Voting Form',
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments' => array('eventvoting_form'),
    // Use the default/standard site configuration permission.
    'access arguments' => array('administer site configuration'),
    'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
  );
  return $items;    
}


/**
 * Creates/returns a form to configure the block's variables.
 *
 * @param array $form
 * @param array $form_state
 * @return array
 */
function eventvoting_form($form, &$form_state) {

  $form['event_name'] = array(
        '#title' => t('Select an event:'),
        '#type' => 'textfield',
        '#default_value' => variable_get('event_name'),
        '#required' => TRUE,
        '#weight' => 0,
    );

    $form['city'] = array(
        '#title' => t('Vote for a city:'),
        '#type' => 'textfield',
        '#default_value' => variable_get('city'),
        '#required' => TRUE,
        '#weight' => 0,
    );

    $form['name'] = array(
        '#title' => t('Your name:'),
        '#type' => 'textfield',
        '#default_value' => variable_get('name'),
        '#required' => TRUE,
        '#weight' => 0,
    );

    $form['email'] = array(
        '#title' => t('Your email:'),
        '#type' => 'textfield',
        '#default_value' => variable_get('email'),
        '#required' => TRUE,
        '#weight' => 0,
    );

    $form['save'] = array(
        '#type' => 'submit',
        '#value' => t('Vote'),
      );

    return $form;
}

**<h2><strong>eventheme.tpl.php (inside the "theme" directory)</strong></h2>**

<?php

/*
 * File         : eventtheme.tpl.php
 * Title        : Drupal 7 Event Voting Location form in a block pattern with template file
 * Author       : Kenyon M. Johnston
 *
 */

?>

<div class="event-voting-form">
    <form>  
        <h2>Vote for Next Year's Event</h2>

        <div id="vote_event_name">
            <?php print $vote_event_name; ?>
        </div>

        <div id="data-fieldset">
            <div id="vote_city">
                <?php print $vote_city ?>
            </div>
            <div id="vote_name">
                <?php print $name ?>
            </div>
            <div id="vote_email">
                <?php print $email ?>
            </div>
            <div id="vote_submit">
                <?php print $submit ?>
            </div>
        </div>

    <?php print drupal_render_children($form); ?>
    </form>
</div>
```

My goal is to render my fields of choice.  The theme renders in the block but not the fields,

This has been racking my brain for a few hours now, any help and assistance would be GREATLY appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
function hook_myform_form ($form, &$form_state,$user_id) {

}

function hook_BLOCK_myform_CONTENT() {
  return drupal_get_form('hook_myform_form');
}

function hook_block_info() {
  $blocks = array();

  $blocks['custom_myform_for_homepage'] = array(
    'info' => t('Details'),
  );
  return $blocks;
}

function hook_block_view($delta='') {
  $block = array();
  switch($delta) {
    case 'custom_myform_for_homepage':
      $block['subject'] = t("Details"); 
      $block['content'] = hook_BLOCK_myform_CONTENT();
      break; 
  }
  return $block;
}
```

Then in your theme template.php add

`function yourthemename_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
    $items['hook_myform_form'] = array(
        'render element' => 'form',
        'template' => 'filename_withoutextension',
        'path' => drupal_get_path('theme', 'yourthemename') . '/nameoffolder',
    );
  return $items;
}`

Now in filename_withoutextension tpl file render fields like this.

`print render($form['checkboxes']);`

Answer (score 0):

You can try the code:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_block_info().
 */
function mymodule_block_info() {
  $block['eventvoting_block'] = array(
    'info' => t('Event Voting Form Block'),
    'cache' => DRUPAL_CACHE_PER_ROLE,
  );
  return $block;
}

/**
 * Implementation of hook_block_view()
 */
function mymodule_block_view($delta = '') {
  $block = array();
  switch ($delta) {
    case 'eventvoting_block':
      $block['subject'] = t("Details");
      $block['content'] = mymodule_block_form();
      break;
  }
  return $block;
}

function mymodule_block_form() {
  return drupal_get_form('mymodule_build_block_form');
}

function mymodule_build_block_form($form, &$form_submit) {
  $form['name'] = array(
    '#title' => t('Your name:'),
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#default_value' => variable_get('name'),
    '#required' => TRUE,
    '#weight' => 0,
  );

  $form['email'] = array(
    '#title' => t('Your email:'),
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#default_value' => variable_get('email'),
    '#required' => TRUE,
    '#weight' => 0,
  );

  $form['save'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t('Vote'),
  );
  $form['#theme']='eventvoting';
  return $form;
}

function mymodule_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
  return [
    'eventvoting' => [
      'render element' => 'form',
      'path' => $path . '/templates',
      'template' => 'eventvoting_form',
    ]
  ];
}
```

create file `eventvoting_form.tpl.php` in the module `mymodule/templates/eventvoting_form.tpl.php`
print form field:

```
<?php print render($form['form_id'])?>
<?php print render($form['form_token'])?>
<?php print render($form['name'])?>
<?php print render($form['email'])?>
<?php print render($form['save'])?>
```